# Where is the boost vec(x,y,z) function defined

Tags: c++, boost

I have seen this function  vec(....) in many boost libraries. It constructs a vector with the values you place in it using some template meta-magic to do the type inference. So for example:

`vec(1,2) returns vector<int> filled with 1,2`

`vec(1.1,2.2,3.3) returns vector<float> filled with 1.1,2.2,3.3`

Its really useful for testing as well as for passing vectors valued parameters. But I can;t find which header file it is defined in, and Googling `Boost vec` is completely useless because obviously you get a million results about the vector class.

Does any know where it is defined?

Comment: Where did you see this function used?  I have never seen it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you you are referring to the [boost::assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library?

It not the construction you mention but it is similar.

Comment: I have used boost assign before, and while it has a similar construct it is not exactly what I was looking for. The Assign library still requires you to define the container first. (`vector<int> v;`) and then assign to it (`v+=1,2,3`). The function I am looking for does all of that in one. I will look through the code to see if I can find another boost library that uses it.

Comment: @JHSaunders True, you can use the list_of if you want to initialize in one line vector<int> v=list_of(1)(2)(3);  (not quite as short as you want but still not bad).

Comment: Well I have searched everywhere for my mystery function and come to the conclusion that it must have been a dream or something. Thanks for pointing out list_of(), it does the trick just as well.

Comment: @JHSaunders I think I may have found a source for your vec initialisation - the boost::spirit library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/number_list___stuffing_numbers_into_a_std__vector.html

Answer (score 1):

Is [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) what you're looking for ?